# How to use DateTime?

Tags: datetime

What do I need to include to use DateTime?  More specifically:

`int month = System.DateTime.Now.Month;`

Because I just put it there, and it doesn't recognize it.

Coding in C, with codeblocks

This is the error I am getting:

```
||=== Build: Debug in fm (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
E:\CS50X\Projetos\FM\fm.c|224|error: 'System' undeclared (first use in this function)|
```

I just want to make a getage algorithm, but for that II need to get the current month and year.

Here is DateTime page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.datetime.aspx

Comment: Define "it doesn't recognize it."  What is the error?  If you're coding in C then I don't think this is C code, so that could be the problem...

Comment: @David Im sorry, I updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object you mention (`System.DateTime.Now.Month`) and the documentation to which you link (http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.datetime.aspx) is all in the .NET Framework, used by languages such as C# and Visual Basic.

However, you're trying to compile C code:

```
|=== Build: Debug in fm (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
```

Short answer... You can't use C# objects in C code.  They're completely different languages on completely different platforms.  If you're programming in C, you need to write your code in C.  Different programming languages don't mix together like that.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the help. BTW, do you know any way to get the current month and year in C?

Answer (score 0):

drop system and use this

```
int month = DateTime.Now.Month;
```

Comment: How would that help a C program compile?

Comment: Well, that's great and all, but changing the error message from "System" to "DateTime" really doesn't seem terribly useful. This isn't .NET.

Comment: if its not .Net what is it? the OP should be more clear because the code they are using looks a lot like .Net

Comment: That's the point. They're trying to use .NET code in a straight-up C compiler, as their question clearly shows with the gcc error message.

Comment: they are using the wrong compiler then they should be using csc.exe